# how do i update single value into database using multiple ids in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

any one can help me, how do i update single value into database using multiple ids in laravel?

i have two input fields please check below code

1st input with multi selection (Lead Id's)

```
<select class="form-control" name="assign_lead[]" multiple>

     @foreach ($sys_leads as $name) 

     <option value="{{$name->l_refcode}}">{{$name->l_fname}} {{$d->l_lname}} (Ref. Code: CL-{{$name->l_refcode}})</option>

     @endforeach  

</select>
```

2nd input with single selection

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="assign_emp">
 @foreach ($employee as $emp)

<option value="{{$emp->name}}">{{$emp->name}}</option>

@endforeach  

</select>
```

i want update database based on id , single id update its working, but i want update multiple id's with single single value.

how is this possible with db methode in laravel?

```
 public function assignpost(Request $request){

  $assign_emp = $request->input('assign_emp');
  $l_refcode = $request->input('assign_lead');
  $l_leadassigneddate = date("Y-m-d");


   DB::update('update sys_leads set l_assignedStaff = ?, l_leadassigneddate = ? where l_refcode = ?',[$assign_emp,$l_leadassigneddate,$l_refcode]);

  return redirect('leads')->with([
       'message' => 'Lead Assigned Successfully'
  ]);  
 }
```

Comment: with `WHERE l_refcode IN (1,2,3)` you can select multiple line who will be updated.
I also suggest you to try using Eloquent in Laravel, it's really make thing simplier.

Comment: am using id name  like 0001, 0002, 0003 if i select different ids how to do it eloquent , do you have any example code

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates look for `Mass updates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the method **whereIn()** to constrain the query and the method update of query builder, for example:

```
DB::table('sys_leads')
          ->whereIn('l_refcode ', $l_refcode)
          ->update(['l_assignedStaff' => $assign_emp,
                    'l_leadassigneddate' => $l_leadassigneddate]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to update the multiple rows:

```
DB::update('update sys_leads set l_assignedStaff = ?, l_leadassigneddate = ? where l_refcode IN (?)',[$assign_emp,$l_leadassigneddate,implode(", ",$l_refcode)]);
```